# Flutter: How can I invoke MethodChannel in other Thread

Tags: android, flutter, pytorch

i am currently working on a small machine learning app with Pytorch. I want to use the the CameraStream to predict every 500ms on the current picture the classes. The app should show the camera preview and the output of the predictions. This already works but the platform specific code for the Pytorch prediction blocks the UI thread because it took very long to complete the prediction.

How can I run the MethodChannel invoke in a background thread (compute/isolate) and refresh my ui as soon as the prediction is ready?

my current code:

```
                _controller.startImageStream((image) => (
                      _getPrediction(image)
                ));
```

_controller is my cameracontroller in a FutureBuilder for the preview

and the _getPrediction Method is:

```
Future<void> _getPrediction(CameraImage img) async {
    if((stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds - inferTime.value) >=500){
      try {
        final List<double> result = await platform.invokeMethod(
          'predict_image',
          <String, dynamic>{
            'image_data': img.planes[0].bytes,
          },
        );
        setState(() {
          class1.value = result[0];
          class2.value = result[1];
          class3.value = result[2];
          class4.value = result[3];
          class5.value = result[4];
          class6.value = result[5];
          inferTime.value = result[6];
          if (inferTimeAVG.value == 0.0){
            inferTimeAVG.value = result[6];
          } else{
            inferTimeAVG.value -= (inferTimeAVG.value / movingAVG);
            inferTimeAVG.value += (result[6] / movingAVG);
          }
          fps.value = 1000 / result[6];
        });
        stopwatch.reset();
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }else{

      return;
    }

  }
```

but with this code I always run in a blocking UI of course. I already tried to isolate this function but it didnt work because of shared memory issues. Invoking the methodchannel from a plugin works one or two calls and after that my imagestream dies

My Java Code:

```
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {


        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            switch (call.method) {
                                case "predict_image":
                                    try {

                                        
                                        byte[] byteStream = call.argument("image_data");
                                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteStream, 0, byteStream.length);

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("Pytorch: Main activity", "Error reading", e);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    Tensor inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.bitmapToFloat32Tensor(
                                            bitmap,
                                            TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB,
                                            TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB
                                    );
                                    float[] scores = new float[7];
                                    final long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                                    final Tensor oTensor = module
                                            .forward(IValue.from(inputTensor))
                                            .toTensor();
                                    final long endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                                    float[] preds = oTensor.getDataAsFloatArray();
                                    for(int i=0; i < preds.length; i++){
                                        scores[i] = preds[i];
                                    }
                                    scores[6] = (float) (endTime-startTime);

                                    result.success(scores);

                                    break;
                                case "init_predictor":
                                    String absPath = call.argument("model_path");
                                    module = LiteModuleLoader.load(absPath);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    result.notImplemented();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
```

Comment: What does your Java/Kotlin plugin code look like?

Comment: added the java code :)

Comment: The function you provided to `setMethodCallHandler` will run on the Android UI thread, so you shouldn't do any work there. You can start another Java thread (does Pytorch give you any handy features to do that easily?) and then when that completes you can invoke a Native->Dart method to deliver the results. (Just be sure to post the result to the main looper so that the native-dart call takes place on that thread, not your worker.)

Comment: No PyTorch does not give me any good features for this :/ So i would have to reopen another CameraPreview in Android for taking the pictures. I will look into this today. Thank you